# Insert into Select with group concat

Tags: php, mysql, group-concat

Hi i have a table that has values

```
 domain                 user              groups
 test_at_test.com         john              first
 test_at_test.com         mary              second
 test_at_test.com         john              second
```

etc..

I want to `group concat` that table and insert the values to a new table or `update` the current table i dont have a problem with that and have the new table to be like this

```
domain                user              groups
test_at_test.com         john              first,second
test_at_test.com         mary              second
```

i write the following `command` but i get an `error` Column count doesn't match value count at row 1 
    `INSERT   INTO    newtable`
    `SELECT * , GROUP_CONCAT(groups)`
    `FROM table GROUP BY` 
    `user ORDER BY domain`

Comment: This sounds like a terrible idea. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: because the values in the first table are inserted from a query and i dont want to have each user multiple times because the only field that changes is the group. if there is a way that i can make the concat at the inital insert it would be better but i cant do that. i am new to sql and php!

Comment: Generally, it's a bad idea to store data that can easily be calculated on-the-fly from pre-existing data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your new table has 3 columns but in select the result set will have 4 columns you need to specify columns in your select statement

```
INSERT   INTO    newtable 
SELECT `domain`, `user`,  GROUP_CONCAT(groups)  
FROM table GROUP BY  user 
ORDER BY domain
```

[`DEMO`](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f1feb/1)

> **Note** The result is truncated to the maximum length that is given by the group_concat_max_len system variable, which has a default value
>   of 1024. The value can be set higher, although the effective maximum
>   length of the return value is constrained by the value of
>   max_allowed_packet.